# From array of objects, map values in specific order without repeating the order

Tags: javascript

I’m using `map` to get the values of these object properties in the specified order (`amount`, then `user`, then `date`) in an array for each object:

```js
const data = [
  {
    amount: '100',
    user: 'admin',
    date: 'March 6, 2019'
  },
  {
    amount: '120',
    user: 'admin',
    date: 'March 6, 2019'
  },
  {
    amount: '80',
    user: 'admin',
    date: 'March 7, 2019'
  },
  {
    amount: '200',
    user: 'admin',
    date: 'March 7, 2019'
  }
];
const result = data.map(({ amount, user, date }) => [ amount, user, date ]);

console.log(result);
```

Is it possible to get the same result by *not* repeating `amount, user, date`? I.e. is there some syntax akin to saving `amount, user, date` into `keys` as shown here?

```js
const keys = "amount, user, date"
const result = data.map(({ keys }) => [keys]);
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please only tag one RDBMS - if indeed the RDBMS is at all relevant to the question? Where are you trying to get these values... if JavaScript please remove *all* RDBMS tags.

Comment: can you give example of the expected final output

Comment: This question is seriously unclear. What exactly do you want as a result?

Comment: Edited the question. Is this what you mean? Use `const keys = [ "amount", "user", "date" ];` and `data.map((object) => keys.map((key) => object[key]));` instead. This isn’t possible only with destructuring. (Beware that `keys` is a read-only variable in the console, so you have to use a different variable name in the console. It works fine in a content script or module.)

Comment: Why would you want to do this what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass each object through Object.values to get the values array.  Beware!  If the object properties vary in their order per object, this will produce weird results.

```js
const data = [
  {
    amount: '100',
    user: 'admin',
    date: 'March 6, 2019'
  },
  {
    amount: '120',
    user: 'admin',
    date: 'March 6, 2019'
  },
  {
    amount: '80',
    user: 'admin',
    date: 'March 7, 2019'
  },
  {
    amount: '200',
    user: 'admin',
    date: 'March 7, 2019'
  }
];

const result = data.map(Object.values);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to dynamically destructure based on the string, but that doesn't work. If you *need* to do this you will need to map over each 'key' in the passed string and access the property individually, but this offers little benefit over simply destructuring as you already are, unless you have to receive a dynamic list of properties from an outside source, or as @sebastionsimon points out, you want to repeatedly access these properties. If the latter, an array would be a more efficient means of storing them than a string.

```
const keys = "amount, user, date"
const result = data.map((o) => keys.split(', ').map((key) => o[key]));
```

If the reason is repeated refactoring, you can declare a helper function.

```
const Transaction = ({ amount, user, date }) => [amount, user, date];
const result = data.map(Transaction);
```

```js
const data = [
  { amount: '100', user: 'admin', date: 'March 6, 2019' },
  { amount: '120', user: 'admin', date: 'March 6, 2019' },
  { amount: '80', user: 'admin', date: 'March 7, 2019' },
  { amount: '200', user: 'admin', date: 'March 7, 2019' },
];

const result = data.map(({ amount, user, date }) => [amount, user, date]);

const keys = 'amount, user, date';
const string_result = data.map((o) => keys.split(', ').map((key) => o[key]));

const Transaction = ({ amount, user, date }) => [amount, user, date];

const transaction_result = data.map(Transaction);

console.log('Destructure: \n', result);
console.log('From string: \n', string_result);
console.log('Transaction: \n', transaction_result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: _“absolutely no benefits”_ — except that you don’t need to repeat a potentially long list of properties.

Comment: Sure, but in that case at least store them in an array to begin with, and not a string.

Comment: I believe the string was only used for illustrative purposes in the question.